# Proof of Exercise 1.2 of Reid's Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry: For prime p, condition such that $x^2 + y^2 = p$ has rational solutions

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-geometry

### Exercise statement

Let p be a prime, and by experimenting with various $p$, how can we guess a necessary and sufficient condition for $x^2 + y^2 = p$ to have rational solutions.

### My question

There is a proof given our stackexchange below but it seems that the core part relies on `the theorem of the decomposition of a prime number` thus the detail's omitted.
Unfortunately, I can't seem to find that theorem on the internet and I'm totally new to Number theory. 
`Could someone tell me the following?`

1. What that theorem is + Some intuition of the theorem as to why we get the promised sufficient condition of $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1$ (mod 4) from that theorem?
2. What does it mean to put the ieal $P$ through the quadratic function $N$, i.e., $N(P) = p$? Like, $P$ is generated by $p$ so I can't see why $N$ fixes to $p$ over the entire $P$.

### Proof provided by [Here w/h slight modification](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/185732/rational-solutions-for-arbitrary-p/185751#185751)

Let $p$ be a prime number.
We claim that $x^2 + y^2 = p$ has a rational solution if and only if $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1$ (mod 4).

Let $K = \mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-1})$.
Suppose $x^2 + y^2 = p$ has a rational solution.
Let $\gamma = x + \sqrt{-1}y \in K$.
Then the quadratic function $N(\gamma) = (x + yi) (x - yi) = p$.
Let $A = \mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-1}]$ (Gaussian Integer).
It is well known that $A$ is a principal ideal domain.
Suppose $\gamma = \alpha/\beta$, where $\alpha, \beta \in A$ and $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are relatively prime.
Then $N(\gamma) = N(\alpha)/N(\beta)$.
Hence $N(\alpha) = pN(\beta)$.
Since $\alpha$ and $\beta$ are relatively prime, $N(\alpha)$ and $N(\beta)$ are relatively prime.
Hence $N(\beta)$ is not divisible by $p$.
Since $N(\alpha)$ is divisible by $p$, there exists a prime ideal $P$ dividing $\alpha$ and $p$.
Then $N(P) = p$.
Hence $P \neq pA$.
Hence, by `the theorem of the decomposition of a prime number` in $K$, $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1$ (mod 4).

Conversely suppose $p = 2$ or $p \equiv 1$ (mod 4).
There exists a prime ideal $P$ such that  $N(P) = p$.
Hence $x^2 + y^2 = p$ has an integer solution.
**QED**

### Why not replying to the post of the proof?

It's been almost 10 years since the question posted, so I've decided to make another thread to discuss this.

Comment: I know that recently I've made few threads about Exercise 1.2 of Reid's Undergraduate Algebraic Geometry. But I'm not working on homework or anything, I'm just self-studying. So, sorry for creating similar posts.

Comment: There are many proofs of this, I think you should stick with the methods in the Reid book. Still, there are some very strong conditions you could use: if an integer $n $  is rationally represented by $x^2 + y^2 $  it is also integrally represented.  This sot of thing is in Serre's little book. See Pete L. Clark's first article http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/ADCFormsI.pdf   then an addendum by Dacar http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Dacar_2012.pdf  and my paper with Pete http://alpha.math.uga.edu/~pete/Clark_Jagy_11_13_2013.pdf

Comment: @WillJagy Thank you for your answer! So far, in Ch.1, we focus on studying the conics, but, I've no idea how to go about in this exercise using the results from the chapter. 
My attempt ([here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4778540/exercise-1-2-of-reids-undergraduate-algebraic-geometry)) ended up w/h the pretty similar form of $a^2 + b^2 = p$.... so unsuccessful. 
Could you give me a reference to `the methods` or `many proofs` you mentioned??

Comment: the most direct  would be Cox, here is the first edition   http://www.math.toronto.edu/~ila/Cox-Primes_of_the_form_x2+ny2.pdf  I think the corrections I know about are fixed in the second edition  but are not part of this preview... https://www.google.com/books/edition/Primes_of_the_Form_x2+ny2/NklYBAAAQBAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&printsec=frontcover

Comment: Thank you for the reference, I skimmed through Theorem 1.2, that is, `An odd prime p can be written as x^2 + y^2 iff p \equiv 1 mod 4` which is almost the same as the statement of our interest. But the proof at glance seems irrelevant to the conics we studied in the Ch.1 of Reid's book...?

Comment: well, this next book is written with self-study in mind  https://bookstore.ams.org/mbk-105/    Note that you began with Reid but have not indicated your own direction any more than that.

Comment: @WillJagy, Thank you for providing another reference! Oh, I read a book about Riemann surfaces in complex analysis and have seen many connections to algebraic curves. So I looked up some undergrads level AG book and I've heard that Reid's UG AG might be a good start so I started working on it.